# User: ARN is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: ARN (AWS Integration error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, aqua

I am trying to monitor an AWS Cloud environment using AquaSec. AquaSec helps you connect with your AWS environment by providing a CloudFormation template, which you would deploy at your AWS environment. Once it is deployed, you use it's ARN in AquaSec to connect/integrate both. Any alert in Aquasec would be sent to an SNS Topic which would send it further to a HTTPS endpoint.

This is the CloudFormation template file,

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "Aqua CSPM security scanner cross-account role",
"Parameters": {
    "ExternalId": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Description": "The external ID auto-generated from the Aqua Cloud dashboard. Do not change this value.",
        "AllowedPattern": "[-a-z0-9]*",
        "ConstraintDescription": "Must be lowercase or numbers, no spaces, dashes ok."
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "AquaCSPMRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::057012691312:role/lambda-cloudsploit-api"
                        },
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                        "Condition": {
                            "StringEquals": {
                                "sts:ExternalId": {
                                    "Ref": "ExternalId"
                                }
                            },
                            "IpAddress": {
                                "aws:SourceIp": "3.231.74.65/32"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::057012691312:role/lambda-cloudsploit-collector"
                        },
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                        "Condition": {
                            "StringEquals": {
                                "sts:ExternalId": {
                                    "Ref": "ExternalId"
                                }
                            },
                            "IpAddress": {
                                "aws:SourceIp": "3.231.74.65/32"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::057012691312:role/lambda-cloudsploit-remediator"
                        },
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                        "Condition": {
                            "StringEquals": {
                                "sts:ExternalId": {
                                    "Ref": "ExternalId"
                                }
                            },
                            "IpAddress": {
                                "aws:SourceIp": "3.231.74.65/32"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::057012691312:role/lambda-cloudsploit-tasks"
                        },
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                        "Condition": {
                            "StringEquals": {
                                "sts:ExternalId": {
                                    "Ref": "ExternalId"
                                }
                            },
                            "IpAddress": {
                                "aws:SourceIp": "3.231.74.65/32"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Policies": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "aqua-cspm-supplemental-policy",
                    "PolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [
                            {
                                "Effect": "Allow",
                                "Action": [
                                    "ses:DescribeActiveReceiptRuleSet",
                                    "athena:GetWorkGroup",
                                    "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                                    "logs:DescribeMetricFilters",
                                    "elastictranscoder:ListPipelines",
                                    "elasticfilesystem:DescribeFileSystems",
                                    "servicequotas:ListServiceQuotas",
                                    "ssm:ListAssociations",
                                    "dlm:GetLifecyclePolicies",
                                    "airflow:ListEnvironments",
                                    "glue:GetSecurityConfigurations",
                                    "devops-guru:ListNotificationChannels"
                                ],
                                "Resource": "*"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecurityAudit"
            ]
        }
    }
},
"Outputs": {
    "AquaCSPMeArn": {
        "Description": "The role ARN of the cross-account user. Copy this into Aqua Cloud.",
        "Value": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "AquaCSPMRole",
                "Arn"
            ]
        }
    },
    "StackVersion": {
        "Description": "The Aqua CSPM stack version.",
        "Value": "2.0"
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to setup an **Amazon SNS Topic**, use its ARN here at Aquasec to send out alerts. Once i create an SNS topic, and copy it's ARN at Aquasec, and try out a test notification - I keep getting the error,

> {
> "message": "User: arn:aws:sts::057012691312:assumed-role/lambda-cloudsploit-api/cloudsploit-api is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:940386435759:Sample_Aqua_Integration",
> "code": "AuthorizationError",
> "time": "2021-04-19T22:15:54.463Z",
> "requestId": "bc808944-3430-5683-aed1-d1bc376a70f5",
> "statusCode": 403,
> "retryable": false,
> "retryDelay": 50.2772842473471
> }

I have tried nearly every possible way - changed topic policy(various combinations of "Principle" field) in the SNS Topic, tried to give permissions in the specific IAM role. Nothing seems to work and I get the same error.
I feel it has to do something with the template file (in the '*assumeRole*' configuration) ?

Any suggestions on how and what to change/try?
Thanks

Comment: What is the policy you are showing? SNS topic policy? Lambda execution role? User policy?

Comment: The first one is cloudformation template for integrating aquasec and aws, second one is the error when I execute an SNS topic